# Awkward guiceyfruit transitive dependency on an older version of guice

Tags: jms, guice, guava, dependency-management

I'm writing a small Camel-based JMS app using guice 3.0 to wire everything up. The CamelModule unfortunately relies on guiceyfruit, the current version of which has a transitive dependency on guice 2.0!

Between guice 2.0 and 3.0 some deprecated classes were removed, notably com.google.inject.internal.Sets/Lists/Maps!

Excluding the transitive dependency on guice 2.0 and using guice 3.0 exclusively doesn't work because of the removed classes; There will be ClassNotFoundExceptions at runtime.

My solution was to implement the three classes in my own project and the single method from each that guiceyfruit requires (newArrayList, newHashSet, newHashMap). These just delegate to google guava implementations of these methods

I no longer get ClassNotFound exceptions but I can't help feeling there is a more effective way to achieve this.

What's the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: It looks like guiceyfruit hasn't changed since 2009, even though there are bugs similar to yours reported (see https://code.google.com/p/guiceyfruit/issues/detail?id=24). I would try to remove the dependency on guiceyfruit

Comment: Guiceyfruit was opensource. Maybe you can grab the source and see how easy it would be to migrate its dependencies to Guice 3.0? Barring that I think your solution is a fine one - especially in terms of effort.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll continue with my current solution. @NamshubWriter I'm not sure how to remove the dependency, short of writing my own camel-guice integration for which I lack the time and know-how. I have considered it out of interest but I might emerge from the rabbit hole, days later, with only a guice module to show for it :p

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue and a fix should be in Camel 2.11: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-4209